# Bind data ObjectDataSource to Label

Tags: asp.net, label, objectdatasource, formview

How do you bind data from an ObjectDataSource to a label form an Formview (Detailsview)?

This is my code from the DetailsView () 
Normally it shows the ID of Afstand (Distance) but it has to show instead of id=1 --> "5km"

```
ID_AFSTAND:

            <asp:Label ID="ID_AFSTANDLabel" runat="server" DataSourceId="dtsrcAFstandKilometer" Text='<%# Bind("AFSTAND") %>' DataValueField="ID_AFSTAND" DataTextField="AFSTAND" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  />
            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dtsrcAFstandKilometer" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetDataAfstand" TypeName="InschrijvenTableAdapters.tblAfstandenTableAdapter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
            <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've never seen binding of a label to any type of data source done from the design view and I'm not sure whether it's even possible because the data sources generally contain multiple records and to bind to a label you would need to implement some kind of *"top 1" type logic* in the binding.But this can quite easily be done in the code behind, here's an exmple:

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView afstande = dtsrcAFstandKilometer.Select() as DataView;
    string firstID = afstande[0][0].ToString();
    string firstKM = afstande[0][1].ToString();

    ID_AFSTANDLabel.Text = firstKM;
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:Label ID="ID_AFSTANDLabel" runat="server" />
```